# put method in angularjs gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, put

> I want that values in the api will update and not create a new data.
>   The HTML code on ejs page is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntr">

    <label>Items</label><br>
    <label>{{propertyvalue}}</label>
    <md-input-container>

      <input ng-model="property" ng-hide="ptext">
    </md-input-container>
    <i class="material-icons" ng-click="hidepr()" ng-hide="hideP">&#xE22B;</i>
    <i class="material-icons" ng-hide="hidePropertysave" ng-click="save()">&#xE161;</i>
    <br>


  </div>
</div>
```

> code on model is:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
     name:'String'
  }
};
```

> Code on angular controller is :

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCntr',function($scope,$http){

$scope.save=function(){
  var data = {
    name: $scope.property,
  };
  $http.put('http://localhost:1337/Changelabel',data).then(function(res){

      $scope.propertyvalue = res.data.name;

  },function (err) {
    console.log("error");
  })
}
```

> I need help to understand how can i update the value in the schema

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually get CORS related errors? (check the browser console when you query)

Comment: Are you sure if the API is working correctly? Do this request in Postman and see if it works.